# You have brains in your head

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number

"You have brains in your head" is quoted from Dr. Seuss' "Oh, the Places You'll Go!". My question is, should it be 'heads' instead of 'head'? How come more than one brain in one single head?

Comment: "Brains" is often used in this fashion.  It is, oddly, a sort of "mass noun", just like "water" or "sand".

Comment: There is nothing wrong with 'brains', since 'you' refers to more than 1 person here. By the same token, 'heads' (plural) should be used instead of 'head' (singular)... That's what I thought.

Comment: @Lone Look at the second sense of [*brain*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brain) at Merriam-Webster. The plural form is often used to describe somebody who is intelligent. Either somebody *is* ***the brains*** behind something, or somebody *has got* ***brains***. In the phrase in the question, it's not talking about the organ but about intelligence.

Comment: Thank you Jason, but the next sentence in this poem is "You have feet in your shoes." To make the structure parallel, 'head' should be 'heads' so that it can correspond with 'shoes' . Right?

Comment: Why? We have one head and two feet.

Comment: Hot Licks gave the answer, "Brains" is colloquial/informal English and roughly equivalent to "intelligence". The word, "brains" does not directly refer to the physical organ in your head. ++ A: "How can I open this bottle?" B: "Use your brains." = "Use your intelligence." = Use your intelligence to think of a way of opening it."